# How to handle “Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.” on Desktop with Chrome 64?

Tags: playback, domexception

How to handle “Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.” on Desktop with Chrome 64 and HTML5 Video tag.

Answer (score 4):

In modern versions of Chrome, you can’t have videos autoplay with sound enabled by default.

You need to add the `muted` property to your HTML5  tag:

```
muted="muted"
```